# How to create data structure in Tcl?

Tags: data-structures, lisp, tcl

I am translating some lisp code to Tcl and wonder if there is anything like lisp's defstruct in Tcl for creating data structures?

If nothing is built into Tcl, what extension packages to Tcl would you recommend that can be used in a commercial application.

Thanks.

-William

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [dict](http://wiki.tcl.tk/5042)ionaries, which work more or less like a hashmap. You can set the key/value pairs much like you would any other structure.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the pages on Rosetta Code under [Data Structures](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Data_Structures). They all have Tcl examples.

Comment: Seems that associative array in Tcl is instance based and not type based.  Do you know of any extensions to Tcl that provide this?

Comment: No, sorry. I just happen to know that one of the Tcl Core Team members provides many Tcl solutions to tasks on RC. I don't speak any Tcl, unfortunately.

Comment: Tcl is not a typed language: "everything is a string" is a mantra. I'd go with `dict` for complex data structures, or use an OO package like Snit (http://wiki.tcl.tk/snit)

Answer (score 0):

[Tcl tutor](http://www.msen.com/~clif/TclTutor.html) is having 44-47 lessons on dictionaries.